# Cambiar el color de un botón MaterialButton de manera programática

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estoy usando `MaterialButton` de la librería `support.design`.
Comunmente para cambiar el color de un botón normal uso este código:

```
var myButton = findViewByid(.....)
myButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myColor)
```

Pero para este `MaterialButton` el mismo código no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta,
para este caso particular cambie:

```
myButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myColor)
```

por lo siguiente:

```
myButton.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this@MyActivity, R.color.myColor)
```

Esto mismo lo he testeado y funciona perfectamente.